# Using the Pigeonhole principle

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

> By placing 27 squares with an area of 1 meter inside of a circle with the radius of 2 meters, prove that exist such a point that belongs to 3 different squares. (each one of the squares $\subseteq$ in the circle completely)

now I know that the combined area of the squares is 27 and 2 combined area of the circles is only $8\pi<27$ so the point that I need to prove that exist is indeed exist but I can't figure out how to do it formally with the Pigeonhole principle.

thanks in advance and sorry about the english

edited: I need a solution that involves the Pigeonhole principle

Comment: I would think something like the following, but this argument doesn't really contain the pigeon hole principle: Assume you fill up the circle with these 27 squares such that no point belongs to three squares. Divide the circle into three regions: points which belong to 0, 1 or 2 squares and call these regions $R_0$, $R_1$, $R_2$. We have $R_2\leq R_1+R_2\leq 4\pi$. The combined area of the squares is $27=R_1+2R_2=(R_1+R_2)+R_2\leq 4\pi +4\pi<27$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

At first, packing like following image. $S_{rest}=2^2π-12=0.56$. This is limit packing. When full packing with 13 squares in one method, if rest one area of a square size, it's contradict against full packed. Therefore 13's packing of two type doesn't never lose one area of square size simultaneously. Therefore PHP prove.

[image]